# Is there a PyTorch with CUDA Unified GPU-CPU Memory fork?

Tags: pytorch, unified-memory

So Training a DNN model can be a pain when a batch of one image takes 15GB. Speed is not so important for me, yet to fit bigger batches (and models is). So I wonder if there is a PyTorch with CUDA Unified Memory fork or something like that to fit giant models (having 16gb per GPU RAM, yet 250 on CPU side it seems quite resonable)?

Comment: It seems like even if such a solution existed the CPU part would be such a bottleneck that you would probably not benefit much from the GPU. Have you considered using [gradient accumulation](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-implement-accumulated-gradient/3822)? Though if you use batch-normalization layers this can become tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about the time it takes, but need large batches, you can use a more slow approach. Say you need to have a batch of 128 samples but your gpu memory fits only 8 samples. You can create smaller batches of 8 samples and then average their gradients.

For each small batch of 8 samples that you evaluate, you keep the `.grad` of each parameter in your cpu memory. You keep a list of grads for each of your models parameters. After you have gathered the grads for 16 batches of 8 samples (128 samples in total) you can average the gradients of each parameter and put the result back into the `.grad` attribute of each parameter.

You can then call the `.step()` of your optimizer. This should yield exactly the same results as if you were using a large batch of 128 samples.